# How to handle request to callback URL with Firebase OAuth?

Tags: firebase, rest, twitter, oauth, firebase-authentication

I am implementing Firebase OAuth with Twitter in a Game Maker app.
Note that Game Maker does not support SDKs so I am using 3-legged OAuth sign-in with REST.
After redirecting the user to the sign-in page for Twitter, I don't know how to handle the callback to the firebase URL and get the authentication data back to my Game Maker client.

I got the first step of the sign-in working, which is the POST oauth/request_token request to api.twitter.com; in the response I'm receiving oauth_token, oauth_token_secret and oauth_callback_confirmed.

After that, I'm opening the following URL in the user's browser: "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=[oauth_token]"

That sends me to the Twitter sign-in page, which then redirects to the callback URL set in Firebase (and whitelisted in the Twitter dev console): "https://[APPNAME].firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler" with the oauth_token and oauth_verifier query parameters.

The guide says this about this step of the 3-legged sign-in:

> Upon a successful authentication, your callback_url would receive a request containing the oauth_token and oauth_verifier parameters. Your application should verify that the token matches the request token received in step 1.

I don't know how to reiceve the request to the callback_url and process it. Is it something I'm supposed to do from Firebase itself? Is my Game Maker client supposed to do it with a GET request? I have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up a Cloud Function as a callback.
This way I am retrieving the response directly from the function and storing the data/errors in the database.

Comment: Could you please show me how you used cloud function as a callback. I would like to use this option too.